# when a record is clicked from a div it must show that selected record into another div

Tags: javascript, html

i have two sections in my page. There is a list of records on left hand side and right side is blank. When a record is selected from left side it should show on right side and the record should be there on left side it shouldn't move.By using javascript.

image shows what actually have to do by selecting a record it should display on another side
[image]

```
 function transfer(){
         var x = document.getElementById("custlist").innerHTML;
          localStorage.detail = ("custdetail",x);
          document.getElementById("customerdisplay").innerHTML = localStorage.detail; 
        }
```

Comment: What is `localStorage.detail = ("custdetail", x)` supposed to do? I think you meant `localStorage.custdetail = x;`

Comment: You should pass the DIV that the user clicked on to the `transfer()` function as an argument, and get the inner HTML of that element instead of hard-coding a specific ID.